# Python argparse: command-line argument that can be either named or positional

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse, python-2.x

I am trying to make a Python program that uses the `argparse` module to parse command-line options.

I want to make an optional argument that can either be named or positional. For example, I want `myScript --username=batman` to do the same thing as `myScript batman`. I also want `myScript` without a username to be valid. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

I tried various things similar to the code below without any success.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-u", "--user-name", default="admin")
group.add_argument("user-name", default="admin")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

**EDIT:** The above code throws an exception saying `ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional`.

I am using Python 2.7.2 on OS X 10.8.4.

**EDIT**: I tried Gabriel Jacobsohn's suggestion but I couldn't get it working correctly in all cases.

I tried this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-u", "--user-name", default="admin", nargs="?")
group.add_argument("user_name", default="admin", nargs="?")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

and running `myScript batman` would print `Namespace(user_name='batman')`, but `myScript -u batman` and `myScript --user-name=batman` would print `Namespace(user_name='admin')`.

I tried changing the name `user-name` to `user_name` in the 1st `add_argument` line and that sometimes resulted in both `batman` and `admin` in the namespace or an error, depending on how I ran the program.

I tried changing the name `user_name` to `user-name` in the 2nd `add_argument` line but that would print either `Namespace(user-name='batman', user_name='admin')` or `Namespace(user-name='admin', user_name='batman')`, depending on how I ran the program.

Comment: I would like to mention that what I am trying to do is basically the same thing that [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) does with its `--match` parameter.

Comment: Please look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707234/how-to-create-an-argument-that-is-optional/17707752#17707752)

Comment: Somehow I didn't notice that question. Feel free to mark this question as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 9):

The way the *ArgumentParser* works, it always checks for any trailing positional arguments after it has parsed the optional arguments. So if you have a positional argument with the same name as an optional argument, and it doesn't appear anywhere on the command line, it's guaranteed to override the optional argument (either with its default value or *None*).

Frankly this seems like a bug to me, at least when used in a mutually exclusive group, since if you had specified the parameter explicitly it would have been an error.

That said, my suggested solution, is to give the positional argument a different name.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-u','--username')
group.add_argument('static_username',nargs='?',default='admin')
```

Then when parsing, you use the optional *username* if present, otherwise fallback to the positional *static_username*.

```py
results = parser.parse_args()
username = results.username or results.static_username
```

I realise this isn't a particularly neat solution, but I don't think any of the answers will be.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that I think does everything you want:

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--user-name", default="admin")
    # Gather all extra args into a list named "args.extra"
    parser.add_argument("extra", nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # Set args.user_name to first extra arg if it is not given and len(args.extra) > 0
    if args.user_name == parser.get_default("user_name") and args.extra:
        args.user_name = args.extra.pop(0)
    print args
```

If you run `myScript -u batman` or `myScript --user-name=batman`, `args.user_name` is set to 'batman'.  If you do `myScript batman`, `args.user_name` is again set to 'batman'.  And finally, if you just do `myScript`, `args.user_name` is set to 'admin'.

Also, as an added bonus, you now have all of the extra arguments that were passed to the script stored in `args.extra`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I would change the `args.username = args.extra[0]` to `args.username=args.extra.pop(0)`, that way it doesn't have it show up in two places.

Comment: @Perkins: Hhm...I like that.  It keeps the script cleaner.  Let me do it

Comment: I like your answer. I made a small change to avoid having the default username in two places.

Comment: I decided to award the bounty to @James Holderness. I liked your idea but James's solution indicated to the user that the call to the program is not allowed to have both a named username and a positional username.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "nargs" parameter of the add_argument method.
This way it works for me.
Now you can add the username twice,
so you have to check it and raise an error, if you want.

```py
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("-u", "--user-name", default="admin")
   parser.add_argument("user_name", default="admin", nargs="?")
   args = parser.parse_args()
   print(args)
```

Comment: I tried the code in your answer. It worked fine when I ran `myScript batman` but with `myScript -u batman` or `myScript --user-name=batman`, it ignored my parameter and set the `user_name` value to `admin`.