# How to create an argument that is optional?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Instead of the user having to use `script.py --file c:/stuff/file.txt` is there a way to let the user optionally use the `--file`? So instead, it would look like `script.py c:/stuff/file.txt` but the parser would still know that the user is referring to the --file argument (because it's implied).

Comment: What argument parser are you using? `argparse` has support for this, for example.

Comment: argv would be the concept.

Comment: Examples, since I've tried this with argparse.

Comment: Can I see an example TerribleSwiftTomato?

Comment: argparse supports positional arguments, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Example of a positional argument?

Comment: You gave an example of one: `script.py c:/stuff/file.txt`, the positional argument here is `c:/stuff/file.txt`.

Comment: The tutorial has a section, "Introducing positional arguments", here -> http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
import argparse

class DoNotReplaceAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if not getattr(namespace, self.dest):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is an example.")
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='?', default='', help='specifies a file.', action=DoNotReplaceAction)
parser.add_argument('--file', help='specifies a file.')

args = parser.parse_args()
# check for file argument
if not args.file:
    raise Exception('Missing "file" argument')
```

Look at help message. All arguments are optional

```
usage: test.py [-h] [--file FILE] [file]

This is an example.

positional arguments:
  file         specifies a file.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --file FILE  specifies a file.
```

One thing to notice is that positional `file` will override optional `--file` and set `args.file` to default ''. To overcome this I used custom `action` for positional `file`. It forbids overriding already set properties.

The other thing to notice is rather than raising an `Exception` you could specify default value.

Comment: For the sake of mandating it, please add an `if not args.file:` clause to your example.

Comment: @BrianCain good point. Plus added node on specifying default value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I suspect `argparse` is failing here because the default `dest` for `--file` and `file` are both the `.file` attribute of the created `Namespace`.  Adding a `dest=` could get this to work, but then it's basically back to what I suggested, except for the difference in `nargs` (`'?'` vs `'*'`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've tested my solution. Just add `print args.file` and run script like `./test.py some.txt --file some.xtx` and you should see `some.xtx`. My python version is 2.7.3

Comment: @twil: click the link in my previous comment. It shows the problem. [Here's a test where you can pass your own input](http://ideone.com/2hl2Bs). `./test.py some.txt --file some.xtx` is invalid input: either `some.txt` should be given or `--file some.xtx`, not both.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian updated code. Actually I was wrong stating `--file` overrids `file`. Have to implement custom action.

Comment: This handling of arguments (sharing of data between named and positional) is a new idea and isn't (yet) used in traditional UNIX-flavor command-line tools. As a consequence, argparse wasn't built with this option in mind. That's why either some hackery or patching of its code is needed.

Comment: `nargs='?'` matches `nothing=[]`.  If after parsing all the optionals, the positional hasn't been used, it will be will be used on what's left, hence the `file=""` value.  While you could use a custom action class, it would simpler to just give the optional and positional different `dest`, and use a bit of post argparse logic.

Answer (score 4):

To accept either `--file FILE` or just `FILE`, you could use [`mutually_exclusive_group()`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#argparse.add_mutually_exclusive_group):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='script',
                                 description="This is an example.",
                                 usage='%(prog)s [-h] (--file FILE | FILE)')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('positional_file', nargs='?', help='specifies a file.')
group.add_argument('--file', help='specifies a file.')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
filename = args.positional_file if args.file is None else args.file
```

#### [Examples](http://ideone.com/8jC6kN)

```
['abc'] -> Namespace(file=None, positional_file='abc')

['--file', 'abc'] -> Namespace(file='abc', positional_file=None)

['--file', 'abc', 'def'] -> usage: script [-h] (--file FILE | FILE)
script: error: argument positional_file: not allowed with argument --file

[] -> usage: script [-h] (--file FILE | FILE)
script: error: one of the arguments positional_file --file is required
```

Comment: Nice.  I should go use that in one of my old scripts that grew mutually-exclusive (but both optional) -i and -n arguments. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If I may rephrase your question into the answer, you want a script which, when run as:

- `script blah` treats `blah` as a file name to be opened
- `script --file blah` treats `blah` as a file name to be opened
- `script --file blah eggs` treats `blah` as a file name to be opened, and `eggs` ... how?
- `script blah eggs` treats `blah` ... differently? how?

In any case, I'd still start with argparse:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script to morgle blahs')
parser.add_argument('--file', help='specify file name to be opened')
parser.add_argument('args', metavar='FILE', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

At this point running `./script.py -h` produces:

```
usage: script.py [-h] [--file FILE] [FILE [FILE ...]]

script to morgle blahs

positional arguments:
  FILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --file FILE  specify file name to be opened
```

Additional runs:

```
$ ./script.py
Namespace(args=[], file=None)
$ ./script.py blah
Namespace(args=['blah'], file=None)
$ ./script.py --file blah eggs
Namespace(args=['eggs'], file='blah')
$ ./script.py blah eggs
Namespace(args=['blah', 'eggs'], file=None)
```

So, instead of simply `print args`, now you can test whether `args.file` is `None` (no `--file`) and then check `args.args`, and if `args.file` is *not* `None`, you can still check `args.args`.

If, at some point, you decide in your own code that some combination of arguments is bad/invalid, you can call `parser.error`, e.g.:

```
if args.file is not None and len(args.args) > 0:
    parser.error('use [--file] <filename>, not --file <filename1> <filename2>')
if args.file is None and len(args.args) != 1:
    parser.error('use [--file] <filename>')
```

would demand exactly one argument, whether or not preceded by the `--file` string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `required=True` flag in `argparse`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Describe stuff.")
parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True, help='bar')
```

However, as [this documentation says](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#required) it is considered bad form to make options required, since users expect options to be optional.

You could instead define your required argument and then have the optional `--foo` flag store to this required argument. This might cause the parser to throw an exception though since it may think that you are just ignoring the required argument.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Will this work?")
parser.add_argument('bar', help="required argument")
parser.add_argument('--foo', required=False, help="kind of required argument", dest='bar')
```

I think that the best answer is to just not have a sort-of-required flag. Just make the variable required and define a default value for it in the event that you need something there to use in your program but a default value is applicable somehow:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Other option.")
parser.add_argument('bar', default='value', help="required argument")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your design, there's a principal ambiguity (that's already a reasonable explanation why it isn't implemented by `argparse`):

- If there are more positional arguments after such a "dual-mode" one (say, `foo/--foo` and `bar`) which one should a positional argument be assigned to in a cmdline like `--foo=foo bar`? This becomes even more confusing if there are multiple "dual-mode" args.

In my script I wrote two years ago that used "dual-mode" arguments, I prohibited such input altogether, requiring that "positional-mode" arguments, if any, come first, followed by "named-mode" ones.

The script was in Perl and I used custom logic to implement this after parsing other options with Perl's `Getopt::Long` in "pass-through" mode (it passes through any arguments that aren't recognized).

So I suggest you do the same, using [`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=parse_known_args#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args).